# Explain the logic behind this program?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to programming and today i came across this program. How did i get the output as 3? and the jargon used here is quite confusing.

```
class Demo 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Demo d = new Demo(); // what does this really mean?
    System.out.println(d.someMethod(124)); 
}
public int someMethod(int x) 
{
    if(x<=0)
    return 0;
    return 1 + someMethod(x/10);
}
}
```

Comment: Which line of code you didn't understand ?

Comment: It's not jargon. It's code.

Comment: I would recommend to delete this question before your reputatation declines to 1... and for learning about recursion which this program has go to... http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=151

Comment: The question's topic is too vague and the OP basically asks for training. For the sake of education: the method is invoked 3 times (since the argument can be divided 3 times by 10) and thus "1" is returned 3 times and summed up.

Answer (score 3):

below is the answer

```
1 + someMethod(12)
1 + 1+ someMethod(1)
1 + 1+ 1+ someMethod(0)
1 + 1+ 1+ 0
= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Reformatted class with comments:

```
class Demo {

    // static method used to start a Java application
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // create a new instance of the Demo class
        Demo demo = new Demo(); 

        // call instance method someMethod and print the return value
        System.out.println(d.someMethod(124)); 
    }

    // someMethod is a recursive function, that is a function which 
    // calls itself until a stop condition is reached
    public int someMethod(int x) {
        // stop condition
        if(x <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        // recursive call
        return 1 + someMethod(x/10);
    }
}
```

What happens:

```
1 call someMethod(124/10)
2 call someMethod(12/10)
3 call someMethod(1/10)
4 return 0 (because 1/10 == 0 the stop condition is reached)
3 return 1 + 0
2 return 1 + 1 + 0
1 return 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

so the return value is 3.

Note that 1/10 == 0 because the result is floored (the remaining decimals are removed to make it an int).

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you create a Demo object with name d.Via this object you call a method named someMethod(x).
This method returns 0 if the input parameter is <=0 or in any other case 1 + someMethod(x/10).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Demo d = new Demo();
```

This line means that you are initialising a new object with name 'd' from a class called Demo (which is also your main class). If you don't understand what objects and classes are, read up on it elsewhere, because it is a very major topic in Java.
Personally this has helped me the most: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

```
public int someMethod(int x) {

if(x<=0)
return 0;
return 1 + someMethod(x/10); }
```

This method is acting kind of like a loop. You are passing a value of 124 from:

```
System.out.println(d.someMethod(124));
```

here.  124 gets checked if it is smaller of equal to zero. It is not so it gets passed to:

```
 return 1 + someMethod(x/10);
```

124/10 is 12.4, but as x is an int it will round it to 12. And the program carries on until x <= 0, which loops over 2 times like:

```
    1 + someMethod(12)
    1 + 1+ someMethod(1) // 12/10 is 1.2, but gets rounded to 1
    1 + 1+ 1+ someMethod(0) // 1/10 is 0.1, but gets rounded to 0
```

And the program ends as the passed value is 0. So you get 3 as an output.

Answer (score -1):

`Demo d = new Demo()` will call the Constructor of **Demo Class**. If there is not any constructor present in the class then **JVM** will create a default one. That's how the concept behind the object creation in Java.

and look the previous answer how the `someMethod(args)`  will execute.